# QgsPoint invalid argumets in PyQGIS 3

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, point

I get an error:

> "Invalid type in constructor arguments."

for a QgsPoint in QGIS 3.

I was fine in QGIS 2, it never gets to print D

```py
for steps in range(numVertices):
     vertex = geom.vertexAt(steps)
     print("C", vertex)
     pt = QgsPoint(vertex)
     print("D")
     points.append(pt)
```

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 6):

`vertexAt` method returns `QgsPoint`. So, you don't need to construct new one. You get the error since [`QgsPoint` class](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsPoint.html) doesn't have any constructor method which takes a `QgsPoint` argument in QGIS 3 unlike QGIS 2.

Use this:

```
for steps in range(numVertices):
     pt = geom.vertexAt(steps)
     points.append(pt)
```