# "Has no attribute geometry" error when creating polygon with Shapely

Tags: python, qgis-3, geometry, shapely, polygon-creation

In Shapely I am getting an error:

> "has no attribute geometry"

when I try to create a Polygon from a list with `QgsPoint`:

```py
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

points = [<QgsPoint: PointZ (-1.96778375739159395 52.33374644648134222 0)>, <QgsPoint: PointZ (-1.49871941885997595 52.29018234320587766 0)>, <QgsPoint: PointZ (-1.5450353922021689 52.51784333059057275 0)>, <QgsPoint: PointZ (-2.00722642553756803 52.54952364559657241 0)>, <QgsPoint: PointZ (-1.96778375739159395 52.33374644648134222 0)>]

test_polygon = Polygon(points)
```

This was fine in QGIS 2 but not in QGIS 3. How to overcome the error?

Comment: Check also this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173149/getting-list-of-qgspoint-from-polygon-layer-in-pyqgis

Answer (score 2):

I have seen your previous question, where I would like to extend [@KadirŞahbaz's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/430486/99589):

```py
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

...
for steps in range(numVertices):
     pt = geom.vertexAt(steps)
     pt_x = geom.vertexAt(steps).x()
     pt_y = geom.vertexAt(steps).y()
     pt_z = geom.vertexAt(steps).z()
     points.append((pt_x, pt_y, pt_z))

polygon = Polygon(points)
print(polygon.geom_type)
```

As mentioned in the Shapely documentation for the [`Polygon`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#Polygon) class:

> The *Polygon* constructor takes two positional parameters. The first
> is an ordered sequence of `(x, y[, z])` point tuples and is treated
> exactly as in the *LinearRing* case. The second is an optional
> unordered sequence of ring-like sequences specifying the interior
> boundaries or “holes” of the feature.

Therefore, the points should look like:

- a list with tuples:

  ```py
   from shapely.geometry import Polygon

   points = [(0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 0)]
   polygon = Polygon(points)

   print(polygon.geom_type) #Polygon
  ```
- or a list with lists:

  ```py
   from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon

   coords = [[0, 0], [1, 1], [1, 0]]
   polygon = Polygon(coords)

   print(polygon.geom_type) #Polygon
  ```
- or a sequence of [`Point`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#points) classes:

  ```py
   from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon

   coords = [Point(0, 0), Point(1, 1), Point(1, 0)]
   polygon = Polygon(coords)

   print(polygon.geom_type) #Polygon
  ```
- or via creating a [`LinearRing`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#LinearRing) class:

  ```py
   from shapely.geometry import Polygon, LinearRing

   coords = [(0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 0)]
   ring = LinearRing(coords)
   polygon = Polygon(ring)

   print(polygon.geom_type) #Polygon
  ```

---

More information one can get after using the `print(help(Polygon))`:

```
Help on class Polygon in module shapely.geometry.polygon:

class Polygon(shapely.geometry.base.BaseGeometry)
 |  Polygon(shell=None, holes=None)
 |  
 |  A two-dimensional figure bounded by a linear ring
 |  
 |  A polygon has a non-zero area. It may have one or more negative-space
 |  "holes" which are also bounded by linear rings. If any rings cross each
 |  other, the feature is invalid and operations on it may fail.
 |  
 |  Attributes
 |  ----------
 |  exterior : LinearRing
 |      The ring which bounds the positive space of the polygon.
 |  interiors : sequence
 |      A sequence of rings which bound all existing holes.
 |  
 |  Method resolution order:
 |      Polygon
 |      shapely.geometry.base.BaseGeometry
 |      builtins.object
 |  
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __eq__(self, other)
 |      Return self==value.
 |  
 |  __init__(self, shell=None, holes=None)
 |      Parameters
 |      ----------
 |      shell : sequence
 |          A sequence of (x, y [,z]) numeric coordinate pairs or triples.
 |          Also can be a sequence of Point objects.
 |      holes : sequence
 |          A sequence of objects which satisfy the same requirements as the
 |          shell parameters above
 |      
 |      Example
 |      -------
 |      Create a square polygon with no holes
 |      
 |        >>> coords = ((0., 0.), (0., 1.), (1., 1.), (1., 0.), (0., 0.))
 |        >>> polygon = Polygon(coords)
 |        >>> polygon.area
 |        1.0
 |  
 |  __ne__(self, other)
 |      Return self!=value.
 |  
 |  svg(self, scale_factor=1.0, fill_color=None)
 |      Returns SVG path element for the Polygon geometry.
 |      
 |      Parameters
 |      ==========
 |      scale_factor : float
 |          Multiplication factor for the SVG stroke-width.  Default is 1.
 |      fill_color : str, optional
 |          Hex string for fill color. Default is to use "#66cc99" if
 |          geometry is valid, and "#ff3333" if invalid.
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Class methods defined here:
 |  
 |  from_bounds(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax) from builtins.type
 |      Construct a `Polygon()` from spatial bounds.
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data descriptors defined here:
 |  
 |  __array_interface__
 |      Provide the Numpy array protocol.
 |  
 |  __geo_interface__
 |      Dictionary representation of the geometry
 |  
 |  coords
 |      Access to geometry's coordinates (CoordinateSequence)
 |  
 |  ctypes
 |      Return ctypes buffer
 |  
 |  exterior
 |  
 |  interiors
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data and other attributes defined here:
 |  
 |  __hash__ = None
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Methods inherited from shapely.geometry.base.BaseGeometry:
 |  
 |  __and__(self, other)
 |  
 |  __bool__(self)
 |  
 |  __del__(self)
 |  
 |  __nonzero__(self)
 |  
 |  __or__(self, other)
 |  
 |  __reduce__(self)
 |      Helper for pickle.
 |  
 |  __setstate__(self, state)
 |  
 |  __str__(self)
 |      Return str(self).
 |  
 |  __sub__(self, other)
 |  
 |  __xor__(self, other)
 |  
 |  almost_equals(self, other, decimal=6)
 |      Returns True if geometries are equal at all coordinates to a
 |      specified decimal place
 |      
 |      Refers to approximate coordinate equality, which requires coordinates be
 |      approximately equal and in the same order for all components of a geometry.
 |  
 |  buffer(self, distance, resolution=16, quadsegs=None, cap_style=1, join_style=1, mitre_limit=5.0, single_sided=False)
 |      Get a geometry that represents all points within a distance
 |      of this geometry.
 |      
 |      A positive distance produces a dilation, a negative distance an
 |      erosion. A very small or zero distance may sometimes be used to
 |      "tidy" a polygon.
 |      
 |      Parameters
 |      ----------
 |      distance : float
 |          The distance to buffer around the object.
 |      resolution : int, optional
 |          The resolution of the buffer around each vertex of the
 |          object.
 |      quadsegs : int, optional
 |          Sets the number of line segments used to approximate an
 |          angle fillet.  Note: the use of a `quadsegs` parameter is
 |          deprecated and will be gone from the next major release.
 |      cap_style : int, optional
 |          The styles of caps are: CAP_STYLE.round (1), CAP_STYLE.flat
 |          (2), and CAP_STYLE.square (3).
 |      join_style : int, optional
 |          The styles of joins between offset segments are:
 |          JOIN_STYLE.round (1), JOIN_STYLE.mitre (2), and
 |          JOIN_STYLE.bevel (3).
 |      mitre_limit : float, optional
 |          The mitre limit ratio is used for very sharp corners. The
 |          mitre ratio is the ratio of the distance from the corner to
 |          the end of the mitred offset corner. When two line segments
 |          meet at a sharp angle, a miter join will extend the original
 |          geometry. To prevent unreasonable geometry, the mitre limit
 |          allows controlling the maximum length of the join corner.
 |          Corners with a ratio which exceed the limit will be beveled.
 |      single_side : bool, optional
 |          The side used is determined by the sign of the buffer
 |          distance:
 |      
 |              a positive distance indicates the left-hand side
 |              a negative distance indicates the right-hand side
 |      
 |          The single-sided buffer of point geometries is the same as
 |          the regular buffer.  The End Cap Style for single-sided
 |          buffers is always ignored, and forced to the equivalent of
 |          CAP_FLAT.
 |      
 |      Returns
 |      -------
 |      Geometry
 |      
 |      Notes
 |      -----
 |      The return value is a strictly two-dimensional geometry. All
 |      Z coordinates of the original geometry will be ignored.
 |      
 |      Examples
 |      --------
 |      >>> from shapely.wkt import loads
 |      >>> g = loads('POINT (0.0 0.0)')
 |      >>> g.buffer(1.0).area        # 16-gon approx of a unit radius circle
 |      3.1365484905459389
 |      >>> g.buffer(1.0, 128).area   # 128-gon approximation
 |      3.1415138011443009
 |      >>> g.buffer(1.0, 3).area     # triangle approximation
 |      3.0
 |      >>> list(g.buffer(1.0, cap_style=CAP_STYLE.square).exterior.coords)
 |      [(1.0, 1.0), (1.0, -1.0), (-1.0, -1.0), (-1.0, 1.0), (1.0, 1.0)]
 |      >>> g.buffer(1.0, cap_style=CAP_STYLE.square).area
 |      4.0
 |  
 |  contains(self, other)
 |      Returns True if the geometry contains the other, else False
 |  
 |  covers(self, other)
 |      Returns True if the geometry covers the other, else False
 |  
 |  crosses(self, other)
 |      Returns True if the geometries cross, else False
 |  
 |  difference(self, other)
 |      Returns the difference of the geometries
 |  
 |  disjoint(self, other)
 |      Returns True if geometries are disjoint, else False
 |  
 |  distance(self, other)
 |      Unitless distance to other geometry (float)
 |  
 |  empty(self, val=51640517376)
 |  
 |  equals(self, other)
 |      Returns True if geometries are equal, else False
 |      
 |      Refers to point-set equality (or topological equality), and is equivalent to
 |      (self.within(other) & self.contains(other))
 |  
 |  equals_exact(self, other, tolerance)
 |      Returns True if geometries are equal to within a specified
 |      tolerance
 |      
 |      Refers to coordinate equality, which requires coordinates to be equal
 |      and in the same order for all components of a geometry
 |  
 |  geometryType(self)
 |  
 |  hausdorff_distance(self, other)
 |      Unitless hausdorff distance to other geometry (float)
 |  
 |  interpolate(self, distance, normalized=False)
 |      Return a point at the specified distance along a linear geometry
 |      
 |      Negative length values are taken as measured in the reverse
 |      direction from the end of the geometry. Out-of-range index
 |      values are handled by clamping them to the valid range of values.
 |      If the normalized arg is True, the distance will be interpreted as a
 |      fraction of the geometry's length.
 |  
 |  intersection(self, other)
 |      Returns the intersection of the geometries
 |  
 |  intersects(self, other)
 |      Returns True if geometries intersect, else False
 |  
 |  overlaps(self, other)
 |      Returns True if geometries overlap, else False
 |  
 |  project(self, other, normalized=False)
 |      Returns the distance along this geometry to a point nearest the
 |      specified point
 |      
 |      If the normalized arg is True, return the distance normalized to the
 |      length of the linear geometry.
 |  
 |  relate(self, other)
 |      Returns the DE-9IM intersection matrix for the two geometries
 |      (string)
 |  
 |  relate_pattern(self, other, pattern)
 |      Returns True if the DE-9IM string code for the relationship between
 |      the geometries satisfies the pattern, else False
 |  
 |  representative_point(self)
 |      Returns a point guaranteed to be within the object, cheaply.
 |  
 |  simplify(self, tolerance, preserve_topology=True)
 |      Returns a simplified geometry produced by the Douglas-Peucker
 |      algorithm
 |      
 |      Coordinates of the simplified geometry will be no more than the
 |      tolerance distance from the original. Unless the topology preserving
 |      option is used, the algorithm may produce self-intersecting or
 |      otherwise invalid geometries.
 |  
 |  symmetric_difference(self, other)
 |      Returns the symmetric difference of the geometries
 |      (Shapely geometry)
 |  
 |  to_wkb(self)
 |  
 |  to_wkt(self)
 |  
 |  touches(self, other)
 |      Returns True if geometries touch, else False
 |  
 |  union(self, other)
 |      Returns the union of the geometries (Shapely geometry)
 |  
 |  within(self, other)
 |      Returns True if geometry is within the other, else False
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data descriptors inherited from shapely.geometry.base.BaseGeometry:
 |  
 |  __dict__
 |      dictionary for instance variables (if defined)
 |  
 |  __weakref__
 |      list of weak references to the object (if defined)
 |  
 |  area
 |      Unitless area of the geometry (float)
 |  
 |  array_interface_base
 |  
 |  boundary
 |      Returns a lower dimension geometry that bounds the object
 |      
 |      The boundary of a polygon is a line, the boundary of a line is a
 |      collection of points. The boundary of a point is an empty (null)
 |      collection.
 |  
 |  bounds
 |      Returns minimum bounding region (minx, miny, maxx, maxy)
 |  
 |  centroid
 |      Returns the geometric center of the object
 |  
 |  convex_hull
 |      Imagine an elastic band stretched around the geometry: that's a
 |      convex hull, more or less
 |      
 |      The convex hull of a three member multipoint, for example, is a
 |      triangular polygon.
 |  
 |  envelope
 |      A figure that envelopes the geometry
 |  
 |  geom_type
 |      Name of the geometry's type, such as 'Point'
 |  
 |  has_z
 |      True if the geometry's coordinate sequence(s) have z values (are
 |      3-dimensional)
 |  
 |  is_closed
 |      True if the geometry is closed, else False
 |      
 |      Applicable only to 1-D geometries.
 |  
 |  is_empty
 |      True if the set of points in this geometry is empty, else False
 |  
 |  is_ring
 |      True if the geometry is a closed ring, else False
 |  
 |  is_simple
 |      True if the geometry is simple, meaning that any self-intersections
 |      are only at boundary points, else False
 |  
 |  is_valid
 |      True if the geometry is valid (definition depends on sub-class),
 |      else False
 |  
 |  length
 |      Unitless length of the geometry (float)
 |  
 |  minimum_clearance
 |      Unitless distance by which a node could be moved to produce an invalid geometry (float)
 |  
 |  minimum_rotated_rectangle
 |      Returns the general minimum bounding rectangle of
 |      the geometry. Can possibly be rotated. If the convex hull
 |      of the object is a degenerate (line or point) this same degenerate
 |      is returned.
 |  
 |  type
 |  
 |  wkb
 |      WKB representation of the geometry
 |  
 |  wkb_hex
 |      WKB hex representation of the geometry
 |  
 |  wkt
 |      WKT representation of the geometry
 |  
 |  xy
 |      Separate arrays of X and Y coordinate values
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data and other attributes inherited from shapely.geometry.base.BaseGeometry:
 |  
 |  __geom__ = 51640517376
 |  
 |  __p__ = None
 |  
 |  impl = <GEOSImpl object: GEOS C API version (1, 10, 0)>
```

Comment: points=[<QgsPoint: PointZ (-1.96778375739159395 52.33374644648134222 0)>, <QgsPoint: PointZ (-1.49871941885997595 52.29018234320587766 0)>, <QgsPoint: PointZ (-1.5450353922021689 52.51784333059057275 0)>, <QgsPoint: PointZ (-2.00722642553756803 52.54952364559657241 0)>, <QgsPoint: PointZ (-1.96778375739159395 52.33374644648134222 0)>]

Comment: problem appears to bevertex=geom.vertexAt(steps)

Comment: it's producing the above instead of  points=[(-1.96778,52.3337), (-1.49872,52.2902), (-1.54504,52.5178), (-2.00723,52.5495), (-1.96778,52.3337)] which us what QGIS2 produced

Comment: Can you share your original data with me?